# How to ask HR directly about the status of complaint I have made against my boss

Tags: follow-up

I have written a complaint letter about my boss to HR. I haven't yet received any response on that. How do I follow up politely with HR about the status of my complaint?

Comment: email/call your HR representative and ask for a status update.

Answer (score 5):

In many cases, what action is being taken against your boss is not something you will know.  If the boss was put on a formal PIP (Performance Improvement Plan), that is not your business.  So you will need to be willing to communicate with them on things that are your business.

- If the action that caused you to complain is continuing, then you can contact HR and explain that.  At that point, they should either accept the additional information or let you know that your complaint is not appropriate.*
- While you can't ask them what they are doing with the complaint, you can ask if there is anything else you need to do.

If the reason that you complained about the boss goes away: the boss changes behavior, the boss is fired, you are moved, or whatever -- that is probably all you will know about the issue.  And, that is all you need to know.  The reason for the complaint has been resolved.  Isn't that what you wanted?

*If your complaint had to do with harassment, it's probably an appropriate complaint.  If you were complaining because your boss is female or you don't like his hairstyle, or you think she isn't doing appropriate work, the complaint is often invalid.